# How to use next_permutation for just one permutation

Tags: c++

How can I use next_permutation algorithm in c++ to  get just the next permutation of a number rather than all the next permutations.

for eg :  How can i change 1 2 6 4 5  to  1 2 6 5 4.

Comment: At least show your effort first, otherwise someone will downvote your question and in worst-case it can be put **on hold** :)

Comment: You should always try it by yourself. It's very bad to ask question without trying it by yourself. We're not here to do your work, rather we're here to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have tried it before you asked.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm> 

using namespace std;

int main () {
  int myints[] = {1, 2, 6, 4, 5};
  next_permutation(myints,myints+5);
  cout << myints[0] << ' ' << myints[1] << ' ' << myints[2] << ' ' << myints[3] << ' ' << myints[4] << '\n'; 
  return 0;
}
```

If you want to check if the next permutation exist or not you should use :

```
if (next_permutation(myints, myints + n))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(next_permutation(myints,myints+n))
   //print them;
else
{
   //this is the first permutation..no higher permutation.
   //you may print it or something else..
}
```

**From reference:** If the function can determine the next higher permutation, it rearranges the elements as such and returns true. If that was not possible (because it is already at the largest possible permutation), it rearranges the elements according to the first permutation (sorted in ascending order) and returns false.

Just run it once and check the return value..that's all. Try checking the manual once.

### Sample code

```
int main(){
   vector<int> v;
   // get the vector elements

  if (next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()))
     for(vector<int>::iterator it=v.begin();it!=v.end();it++)
         cout<<*it<<endl;
  else
  {
     cout<<"No higher permutation";
     cout<<"initial permutation: "<<endl;
     //....
  }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Neeraj Pandey.: check the answer.